# Leetcode 21. Merge Two Sorted Lists. Struggling to understand how solution works

Tags: python

You can read description of the problem at: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

Definition for singly-linked list:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

I was not really able to come up with a solution on my own, I do not yet understand how ListNodes work. So I found a solution by someone else and I would like to understand how it works. Firstly, take a look at the solution itself:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur = dummy = ListNode()
        while list1 and list2:               
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cur.next = list1
                list1, cur = list1.next, list1
            else:
                cur.next = list2
                list2, cur = list2.next, list2
                
        if list1 or list2:
            cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
            
        return dummy.next
```

I will try to describe my approach to understanding, hope you will be able to follow my thoughts. To understand how it works I tried to print values of `dummy` and `cur` after some blocks of code. Take a look:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur = dummy = ListNode()
        print ("1. dummy = " + str(dummy))
        print ("1. cur = " + str(cur))
        while list1 and list2:            
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cur.next = list1
                list1, cur = list1.next, list1
            else:
                cur.next = list2
                list2, cur = list2.next, list2
            print ("2. dummy = " + str(dummy))
            print ("2. cur = " + str(cur))
                
        if list1 or list2:
            cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
            print ("3. dummy = " + str(dummy))
            print ("3. cur = " + str(cur))

        print("answer = " + str(dummy))
            
        #return dummy.next
```

The program prints values of `dummy` and `cur` before the cycle begins, on every turn of the cycle, after the cycle ends and also it prints the final answer.

Following is part of the outputs in the console:

```
1. dummy = ListNode{val: 0, next: None}
1. cur = ListNode{val: 0, next: None}
#outputs before the cycle began. for now everything is clear: cur = dummy = empty ListNode

2. dummy = ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}
2. cur = ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
#outputs after the first turn of the cycle. and here arises my question.
```

Before the cycle begins, `dummy = ListNode{val: 0, next: None}` and `cur = ListNode{val: 0, next: None}`. The program enters the cycle, goes to `else:` block of code (because `list1.val = 1` is not less than `list2.val = 1`.

Then `cur.next = list2` next node of `cur` is set equal to list2. For now, as I understand it, `cur = dummy = ListNode{val: 0, next: {val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}`. Then `list2, cur = list2.next, list2` sets `list2` equal to `list2.next`. Now `list2 = ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}`. And then `cur = list2`, so `cur = ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}`. As I understand it, `cur = dummy = ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}` But after this, we have a block of code where I print values of `dummy` and `cur`. And they are not what I expected:

```
2. dummy = ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}
2. cur = ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
#outputs after the first turn of the cycle
```

Why does this happen? `dummy` should be the same as `cur`, shouldn't it?

Comment: What is a `ListNode`? That isn't a standard Python object. Where and how is it defined?

Comment: Also, `list1: Optional[ListNode]` doesn't make `list1` an optional argument. You would need `list1: Optional[ListNode] = None`.

Comment: added definition in the beginning of my question.

Comment: Please note the statement ```cur = dummy = ListNode()``` simply assigns two different names to the same variable.  Thus when the function returns ```dummy.next```, it could just as easily returned ```cur.next```.

Comment: @itprorh66 that is not correct, because `cur` is reassigned later on, while `dummy` is not. So at the end of the function they might be pointing to two different list nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then `list2, cur = list2.next, list2` sets `list2` equal to `list2.next`. Now `list2 = ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}`.

So far correct.

> And then `cur = list2`, so `cur = ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}`

Not quite right. Let's take a look at this statement: `a, b = c, d`. You're assuming that the evaluation order is `c -> a=c -> d -> b=d` (probably because you know that in Python expressions are evaluated from left to right), but in the assignment expressions the righthand side is always evaluated before the lefthand side. So the correct evaluation order is `c -> d -> a=c -> b=d`. Because of this ordering statements like `a, b = b, a` will work the way you would expect them to (swapping `a` and `b`). Here's a link to Python doc about this if you're interested: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

So in your example `cur` will be assigned an "old" `list2` value which is `ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}`

Comment: Got it! But I still do not understand the relation between ```dummy``` and ```cur```. ```cur.next = list2``` changes value of both ```cur``` and ```dummy```, but later when ```cur``` is set equal to ```list2```, value of ```dummy``` does not change, it is still the value set by ```cur.next = list2``` block of code. Does ```dummy``` change only when we change ```.next``` node of ```cur```? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Remember that in python variables are just references to objects, they don't hold the object themselves. `cur.next = list2` means "Get the object referenced by `cur` and update its `.next` field". It will affect `dummy.next` since `dummy` references the same object. But `cur = list2` means "Make variable `cur` now reference the object that is referenced by `list2`". So it will not affect `dummy`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, then ```list2, cur = list2.next, list2``` should make ```cur``` point to object ```list2```. But on the next turn of the ```while``` cycle ```if list1.val < list2.val:``` is true and ```cur.next = list1``` still modifies the same ListNode() object, which is pointed to by ```dummy```. Why is that, if ```cur``` now points not to ListNode(), but to ```list2```?